# How can the submit action on a form(<form></form>) be automatically fired when all input elements within this form are completed/filled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit

I want the submit action on a form() to be automatically fired  when all input elements within this form are completed/filled. How to do it using ajax?

Comment: are you sure about this? sounds pretty obtrusive...

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea to me.  What if the user mis-types something in one of the fields?  There's no way to verify and fix the data before it gets submitted.

Comment: I want to do this submit by Ajax.

Comment: I want to submit all input values using ajax.

Comment: karim's means of checking whether all fields are filled is still the way to go; just change the form submit part to an ajax request

Comment: We cant criticize his idea until we know his reasons for using it. For example if the user completes the form and there are no errors. The script can automatically detect that, display a summary of the user inputs, if the user confirms them then we submit. This could be one way. I believe there is not bad idea, is just how do we use it.

Comment: this is pretty bad idea from the usability point of view, no matter what he tries to reach - there are always more usable ways to do this.

Answer (score 11):

Something like the following:

```
$("#myForm :input").blur(function() {
    if($('#myForm :input[value]').length == $('#myForm :input').length) {
        $(this).closest("form").submit(); 
    }
    return false;
});
```

Note the following:

- The [`:input`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/input) selector matches
  all input, textarea, select and
  button elements.
- The [`closest`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/closest) selector returns the closest parent element.

Comment: phew that was quick. nice one.

Comment: +1 for a good answer to the question, but I agree with the commenters who said it sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: I don't think the ':empty' selector will work on input fields of type text the way you expect it to work...

Comment: @karim79 - It was me :) I'm testing this in Firefox 3.5. I have a form with one input element of type text. Typing $(':input:empty')[0] in the Firebug console returns that element no matter what I type into the input field.

Comment: @mtyaka - You were correct. I've edited the answer, and sorry for whining about being down-voted.

Comment: @mtyaka - check out the neat trick (at least I hope) I've used for determining if there are any empty elements.

Comment: About the 'closest' thing: you are on the safe side. But I believe it's not allowed to have <form> within <form> (nested <form>s). I couldn't find the confirmation in HTML spec though. But the browsers don't seem to handle it correctly.

Comment: @karim79 - This seems to work, so I changed the down- into an up-vote! Perhaps the check could even look like this: if (!$('#myForm :input:not([value])').length) { ... }

Answer (score 0):

Update:
In addition to Karim79.

```
$("#myForm :input").blur(function() {
    var hasEmpty = false;
    if($('#myForm :input[value]').length == $('#myForm :input').length) {
        $(this).closest("form").submit();

    var name = "", email = ""; //Get the value for name and email from the form
    var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email;
           $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "page.aspx",
              data: dataString,
              success: function() {
                $('#message').html("<h2>Form Submitted!</h2>");//Display message
              }
             }); 
    }
    return false;
});
```

Try this:

```
$("form")[0].submit();
```

You will need to call this function after a fields has been validate.

And check [this](http://www.bitstorm.org/edwin/jquery/doc/events.html) site.